# Finding substring in pandas frozenset

Tags: python, pandas, substring, frozenset

I'm trying to find a substring in a frozenset, however I'm a bit out of options.

My data structure is a pandas.dataframe (it's from the `association_rules` from the `mlxtend` package if you are familiar with that one) and I want to print all the rows where the antecedents (which is a frozenset) include a specific string.

Sample data:
[image]

```py
    print(rules[rules["antecedents"].str.contains('line', regex=False)])
```

However whenever I run it, I get an Empty Dataframe.

When I try running only the inner function on my series of `rules["antecedents"]`, I get only False values for all entries. But why is that?

Comment: Have you tried `rules[rules["antecedents"].str.contains('line', regex=False) == True]`?

Comment: Because `rules["antecedents"]` is not a string, but a frozenset. Hence `rules["antecedents"].str` is a wrong attempt to get a string representation of a frozenset, which as @adrtam says only gives NaN (arguably it should raise Exception). Since you didn't supply an MCVE, can you please dump the actual value of `rules["antecedents"]`?

Comment: @ElBaulP yes i did, found this answer in another stackoverflow post, sorry for not mentioning. To me it seems that this does the exact same thing. 
@smci The actual type of `rules["antecedents"]` is `pandas.core.series.Series`. What does MCVE stand for? I couldn't find a viable result on google. And thank you for prettifying my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `dataframe.str.*` functions are for string data only. Since your data is not string, it will always be NaN regardless the string representation of it. To prove:

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 5)).astype("object")
>>> x
         0         1         2          3          4
0 -1.17191  -1.92926 -0.831576 -0.0814279   0.099612
1 -1.55183 -0.494855   1.14398   -1.72675 -0.0390948
>>> x[0].str.contains("-1")
0   NaN
1   NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

What can you do:

Use `apply`:

```
>>> x[0].apply(lambda x: "-1" in str(x))
0    True
1    True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

So your code should write:

```
print(rules[rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: 'line' in str(x))])
```

You might want to use `'line' in x` if you mean an exact match on element

Comment: Thank you for this! I stumbled upon a similar solution today but looks like I got something wrong. This kind of applying lambda functions to dataframes looks very powerful, maybe I should look into that a bit more.