# How to find Exact String match using Lambda function while comparing frozen sets?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

While following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55402994/5750547) by @adrtam. I tried to find exact match for line using

A)

```
print(rules[rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: 'line' in x)])
```

and

B)

```
print(rules[rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: 'line' == x)])
```

C)

```
print(rules[rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: 'line' == str(x))])
```

A returns the same result of

```
print(rules[rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: 'line' in str(x))])
```

B and C returns an empty dataframe. I want to print rows with only exact match (not contains). How do I do this with lambda function?

P.S. Posting as a question because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: use if condition `print(rules[rules["antecedents"].apply(lambda x: if('line' == x))])` or else use `print(rules[rules["antecedents"] == 'line'])`

Comment: Why do you want to 'do this with lambda function'? As answer by @jezrael suggests, why not just use that?

Comment: Yes that's the easiest way to do it. In retrospect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need compare by `frozenset`:

```
print(rules[rules["antecedents"] == frozenset(['line'])])
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I get ValueError: "frozenset" is not a supported function